# getting repeated json data in node js code

Tags: mysql, node.js

this is my node.js code when I send http get request, from my app I get repeated json data each time requesting. This means previous session doesnt expire if new request comes it sends same json data twice, thrice and so on.

```
app.get('/ecom/products', function (req, res) {
  mysql.Connection.query('select * from product', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {

      throw err;
      res.end("error!!!");
    }
    else if (result.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        objs.push({
          name: result[i].name,
          description: result[i].description,
          category: result[i].category,
          price: result[i].price,
          quantity: result[i].quantity,
          shipping: result[i].shipping,
          location: result[i].location,
          color: result[i].color,
          link: result[i].link
        });
      }
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(objs));
    }
    else {
      console.log('error occured');
      res.end("error occured!");
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Where is `objs` declared?

Comment: it is global. in the top after module declaration

Comment: If the `objs` array is declared globally it is created once andjust  keeps getting data pushed into it. You need to declare `objs` within the scope of the route. This way it is created fresh when the route is called. It will be empty until you push the next object into it and always return one single thing instead of accumulated things.

Answer (score 0):

objs array is declared globally it is created once andjust keeps getting data pushed into it. You need to declare objs for every new request. So It should be :

```
app.get('/ecom/products', function (req, res) {
  mysql.Connection.query('select * from product', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {

      throw err;
      res.end("error!!!");
    }
    else if (result.length > 0) {
     var objs = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        objs.push({
          name: result[i].name,
          description: result[i].description,
          category: result[i].category,
          price: result[i].price,
          quantity: result[i].quantity,
          shipping: result[i].shipping,
          location: result[i].location,
          color: result[i].color,
          link: result[i].link
        });
      }
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(objs));
    }
    else {
      console.log('error occured');
      res.end("error occured!");
    }
  })
});
```